# Who do I report a hacked server to?

Tags: security

This server http://62.193.248.163/ is used to hack Trixbox 2.6 PBX's.

I can't tell if this server is a customers of http://www.amenworld.com/, or is it is actually one of theirs?

Who should I report hacked servers to?

I can't find the owner =(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

from thier whois :

> descr:          For Spam/Abuse requests please send mail to abuse@amenworld.com

Send it to that email, if it isn't theirs they will track the customer down. abuse@ is one of the few generic emails that i actually get responses (albeit mostly automated) from no-a-days

Comment: Before you go thru the effort of doing so, you might want to lookup if the hack is recent. A lot of times hackers will self-report their actions at http://www.zone-h.org/archive, and, if it is very recent, it might be useless to report? the affected people might be already trying to fix the damage.

Comment: It's never useless to report. Worst case, it gets reported twice.